# different css reset for every browser ,is this a good idea to get maximum compatibility with less efforts?

Tags: css, xhtml

different css reset for every browser ,is this a good idea to get maximum compatibility with less efforts?

I found this on searching google http://www.iecss.com/

> The UA Style Sheet is a simple set of
>   css styles that each web browser uses
>   before any other css styles are
>   applied.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a different CSS reset for every browser; one is enough. I [personally like this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

The point of global CSS reset is that you don't get the differences that different browsers have. Having a different CSS reset for each browser would kind of destroy the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you could better/perfect your layout with different css style sheets, it is of course good idea. However you need to use sort of conditional statements (IE for example) to load a style sheet only for specific browsers in order to make sure that no other styles are loaded which may not be needed.

Except for the IE, most styles work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want a different set of styles applied to each browser in the first place? all you need is a good reset (like meyer's as mentioned by Andreas Bonini) css and separate stylesheets to handle IE hacks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Reset is used to just remove any differences between different browser layout defaults.
so,i t doesn't make sense to use different resets per browser.

The popular resets are 
 1. Eric Meyer's CSS Reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
 2. YIU CSS Reset http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Use whatever you feel suits you. But surely don't use diff. resets per browser.